# How to pass the API Response Time from a Fetch function to another async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, fetch-api, testcafe

I am able to get the API Response Time (duration) in the 'makeAPICall' function.
Now I need to pass it(the value of the duration variable)to another async function.
I am wondering if you could please provide the solution?

```
const makeApiCall = ClientFunction(() => {
  console.time("timer1");
  const testLocation = () => fetch('https://xxxxxx',
    {method : 'GET',
      headers:{
        hash: 'xxxxx',
        id: 'xxxxxxxxc'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let duration = console.timeEnd("timer1");
      console.log(duration);
    });
  return testLocation();
});



test('test', async t => {
  await makeApiCall();
  console.log(duration)?????
});
```

Answer (score 4):

1st problem: `console.timeEnd` does not return anything, it print the ellapsed time to the console. Use `performance.now()` instead or just `Date`.

2)You should then return the duration from the last `then`.

```
const makeApiCall = ClientFunction(() => {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  const testLocation = () => fetch('https://xxxxxx',
    {method : 'GET',
      headers:{
        hash: 'xxxxx',
        id: 'xxxxxxxxc'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       const end = new Date().getTime();
       return end - start;
    });
  return testLocation();  // This returns a Promise<number>
});



test('test', async t => {
  const duration = await makeApiCall();
  console.log(duration)?????
});
```

Comment: @ hansmaad

Thanks for your reply. I got the other error though. 
I have updated my first post above with the new error

Comment: @Negin `console.timeEnd` does not return the time, it prints it to console. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach with the `t.request` method that TestCafe provides for API testing.

```js
fixture `Test API`;

test('Simple Test', async t => {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    const response = await t.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');
    const duration = Date.now() - startTime;

    console.log(`request duration is ${duration}ms`); //request duration is 336ms
    await t.expect(response.status).eql(200);
});
```

However, please note that a request's execution time will not be absolutely accurate because apart from execution of the request itself, the time required to process TestCafe's `t.request` command, the time for messaging and overhead costs will also be included in the measurement. You can use this measurement as a comparative estimate of the query execution time. Also, the [`timeout` option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403971/guides/intermediate-guides/api-testing#request-timeout) is available.